# Do Jehovah's Witnesses believe that their "Governing body" will rule the world after "Armageddon"?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses

I understand that Witnesses follow an unelected body of men called a "Governing body".  However I'm unclear on whether or not they believe this governing body is in charge of the earth after their claims of Armageddon.  Is this true?

Comment: What research have you done to indicate that it *might* be?

Comment: An ex-Witness told me.  So I'm trying to see if that's true.

Comment: I voted it up. This question has potential, since it focuses on eschatology.

Answer (score 4):

Read this article:

> http://www.jw.org/en/publications/magazines/w20130715/who-is-faithful-discreet-slave/
>
> This addresses your question specifically.

Often you won't get the same answer when asking random people from their congregations as some are more in touch with modern developments more than others, as you've just discovered.

Another thing is that the *interpretations on core modern fulfilments often change*: 2013 changed the governing body's role slightly. The "wheat and weeds" understanding also recently changed.

**The answer is** "No" they do not believe they will exclusively "rule the world", but are *part* of the 144,000 which serve as Kings and Priests under Christ, obeying him as co-rulers. They presently find themselves to to have a unique role among the anointed, that having changed to "Faithful and Discreet Slave", which dispenses food (teachings) in due season/proper time.

Comment: So the hierarchy they support now will no longer exist in this hypothetical scenario?  No Witness will have leadership over another?

Comment: 2 Corinthians 1:24 -- is the motto (Overseers not masters over our faith). There is no hierarchy.

Comment: To my understanding, having spoken to  many Witnesses, there is a heirarchy because the governing body IS unelected and dictates what literature and rules elders and followers must follow.

Comment: You are correct in many ways. We have a hierarchy, but we are individually answerable to only God and Christ. So if we were ever asked to do something contrary to bible commands then we would obey God rather than those men. In that way they aren't really leaders as much as they are guides.

Comment: Let's keep the comments restricted to clarifying the answer. A remind that the purpose of this site is to provide information about what people believe, not determine who is right and who is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

We do have an unelected Governing Body. Currently there are 8 men on the body. The term "governing body" is synonymous with the "faithful and discreet slave" (Matthew 24:45)

Jehovah's Witnesses believe that 144,000 men and women will be co-rulers with Jesus in heaven and rule over the earth (Revelation 20:4). Of course they won't be humans at that time. They will be spirit creatures like Jesus; a new creation (2Co 5:16, 17). The members of the Governing Body are part of this 144,000 and will rule in heaven if they finish their earthly life in a faithful state.